# Calling a server method that is outside of the Hub class from the client in SignalR

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, signalr, taskfactory

Consider the class below:

```
using Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR;
public class TwitterStream
    {
        // Hub Context
        IHubContext context = GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<GeoFeedHub>();

        public void ChangeStreamBounds(double latitude, double longitude)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(latitude + "-" + longitude);
        }

        // Lots of other interesting code redacted
   }
```

Is it possible to call the `ChangeStreamBounds` method from the client even though it is outside of the Hub class? It's possible to call client functions from the server (and from outside of the Hub class) but is it possible to do it the other way round?

Unfortunately I've backed myself into a bit of a corner and the code must be executed from the class that I've written (not from the Hub itself - unless of course you can run a SignalR Hub as a Task factory)

Comment: Why can you not put a method in `GeoFeedHub` that gets called by the client, and then call `ChangeStreamBounds` on an instance of your `TwitterStream` from there?

Comment: @RyanErdmann I'm creating an instance of the `TwitterStream` class using `Task.Factory.StartNew(() => new TwitterStream());` in `Global.asax` / `Application_Start`.

Comment: Interesting.  What is the purpose of `TwitterStream`?  It seems like  `TwitterStream` is essentially a singleton instance for your application?

Comment: `TwitterStream` makes use of the TweetInvi Twitter API C# wrapper to process the Twitter Streaming API asynchronously - lots of tasks and async stuff. I guess you could say that. I can't remember exactly why I have created it as a Task Factory - that's lost in the mists of development now! There's a valid reason definitely.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There may be an answer to your question that involves `HubConnection`s and `IHubProxy`s (which let you bind to hub method calls) or the lower-level API, but I think you may be going about this the wrong way.

Conceptually, you want the `GeoFeedHub` to handle client requests, and the `TwitterStream` class to handle interacting with the Twitter API.  Thus, your `GeoFeedHub` class has a dependency on `TwitterStream`.

It's good that your `TwitterStream` class has `async` methods, and this is [fully supported in SignalR](http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/signalr-20/hubs-api/hubs-api-guide-server#asyncmethods).  You can have async Hub methods that call into `TwitterStream`, which removes the need for your `TaskFactory` usage in `Global.asax`.

Instead of creating your `TwitterStream` at application start and trying to find a way to bind Hub calls to it (a backwards dependency and violation of the Single Responsibility Principle), it would be cleaner to let your Hub stand as the point of contact between your realtime clients, and inject an instance of `TwitterStream` into the `GeoFeedHub` so the Hub can access the Twitter API.

---

Here's some sample code that should illustrate this idea:

```
public class GeoFeedHub : Hub
{
    // Declare dependency on TwitterStream class
    private readonly TwitterStream _twitterStream;

    // Use constructor injection to get an instance of TwitterStream
    public GeoFeedHub(TwitterStream _twitterStream)
    {
        _twitterStream = _twitterStream;
    }

    // Clients can call this method, which uses the instance of TwitterStream
    public async Task SetStreamBounds(double latitude, double longitude)
    {
        await _twitterStream.SetStreamBoundsAsync(latitude, longitude);
    }
}


public class TwitterStream
{
    public TwitterStream() 
    {
    }

    public async Task SetStreamBoundsAsync(double latitude, double longitude)
    {
        // Do something with Twitter here maybe?
        await SomeComponent.SetStreamBoundsAsync(latitude, longitude);
    }

    // More awesome code here
}
```

---

I used DI in the example, so here's some of the glue code you'd need to hook that up.  This code would go into your `App_Start` folder:

```
// Configure Unity as our DI container
public class UnityConfig
{

    private static readonly Lazy<IUnityContainer> Container = new Lazy<IUnityContainer>(() =>
    {
        var container = new UnityContainer();
        RegisterTypes(container);
        return container;
    });

    public static IUnityContainer GetConfiguredContainer()
    {
        return Container.Value;
    }


    private static void RegisterTypes(IUnityContainer container)
    {
        var twitterService = new TwitterService();
        container.RegisterInstance(twitterService);

        /*
         * Using RegisterInstance effectively makes a Singleton instance of 
         * the object accessible throughout the application.  If you don't need 
         * (or want) the class to be shared among all clients, then use 
         * container.RegisterType<TwitterService, TwitterService>();
         * which will create a new instance for each client (i.e. each time a Hub
         * is created, you'll get a brand new TwitterService object)
         */
    }
}


// If you're using ASP.NET, this can be used to set the DependencyResolver for SignalR 
// so it uses your configured container

[assembly: WebActivatorEx.PreApplicationStartMethod(typeof(UnitySignalRActivator), "Start")]
[assembly: WebActivatorEx.ApplicationShutdownMethod(typeof(UnitySignalRActivator), "Shutdown")]

public static class UnitySignalRActivator
{
    public static void Start() 
    {
        var container = UnityConfig.GetConfiguredContainer();
        GlobalHost.DependencyResolver = new SignalRUnityDependencyResolver(container);
    }

    public static void Shutdown()
    {
        var container = UnityConfig.GetConfiguredContainer();
        container.Dispose();
    }
}

public class SignalRUnityDependencyResolver : DefaultDependencyResolver
{
    private readonly IUnityContainer _container;

    public SignalRUnityDependencyResolver(IUnityContainer container)
    {
        _container = container;
    }

    public override object GetService(Type serviceType)
    {
        return _container.IsRegistered(serviceType) 
            ? _container.Resolve(serviceType) 
            : base.GetService(serviceType);
    }

    public override IEnumerable<object> GetServices(Type serviceType)
    {
        return _container.IsRegistered(serviceType) 
            ? _container.ResolveAll(serviceType) 
            : base.GetServices(serviceType);
    }
}
```